# Google signin - Need to permanently save user details on exit

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have integrated [Google sign in sample application](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/signin) with my applications Main Activity.

I have a button in my Navigation header to launch login activity. 
When I login with my google account, it fetches my name and email Id into Navigation Header.

Now the issue is, if I quit this app, I need to sign in again every time. How can I save the login details.

I have gone through multiple articles which talk about Shared Preference, however shared preference doesn't work for me.

Below is one of the code snippet I have tried. I am calling `storeUserDetails()` in `onBackPressed` and `getUserDetails()` in `onCreate()`.

```
public void storeUserDetails(String userName, String emailID){
    mSharedPreference = getSharedPreferences("userDetails",MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mSharedPreference.edit();
    mEditor.putString("userFullName",userName);
    mEditor.putString("userEmailID",emailID);
    mEditor.apply();
}

private String getUserDetails(){
    mSharedPreference = getSharedPreferences("userDetails",MODE_PRIVATE);
    return mSharedPreference.getString("userFullName","@gmail.com");
}
```

Tried this tutorial as well 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Comment: "doesn't work" be specific please, and go and read this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: When I relaunch the app, it goes back to it's original state. Name and Email ID doesn't show up in Navigation Header. I need to signin again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   //First instantiate sharedpreferences

    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    sharedpreferences=getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    private String name,phone,email;


    //OnPause method to save shared preferences when activity is destroyed

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();  // Always call the superclass method first

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

       editor.putString(Name, name);
       editor.putString(Phone, phone);
       editor.putString(Email, email);
       editor.commit();
    }

    //OnResume method used to retrieve sharedpreferences

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first

    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("MyPREFERENCES", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    name = prefs.getString("Name","");
    phone = prefs.getString("Phone","");
    email = prefs.getString("Email","");

    }
```

Also to handle the login issue, you could use your launcher activity and sharedpreferences to check if Name is null, if it isn't then navigate to your mainactivity, and if it is then navigate to login, then on your logout function just make sure you clear the sharedpreferences.